# testing if DB update was successful with linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using linq-to-sql to update an entry in the table. I'm first fetching a record and then I'm doing this:

```
using (MyDC TheDC = new MyDC())
{
  // fetch record
  // do updates

  TheDC.SubmitChanges();

}
```

After I submit the changes, I just go on with my code.

How do I know the update really happened?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I know the update really happened?

No exception was thrown.

Other than that you could use the [GetChangeSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.getchangeset.aspx) method to get the modified objects tracked by the data context.